# Создание ленты новостей в Android

Tags: java, android, вконтакте

Нужно реализовать просмотр ленты пользователя ВКонтакте, в принципе все отлично, но не могу понять как реализовать показ прикрепленных фотографий, видео и музыки в посте? Как правильно это реализовать? Может у кого то есть примеры? Так же интересует **как реализовать показ прикрепленных фото и видео, такой плиткой**. Естественно размеры фотографий известны.

Проще говоря, вот примеры просмотра постов ВКонтакте, с прикрепленными фотографиями, видео и музыкой. Как правильно реализовать такое же?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Тебе может помочь TwoWayView от Lucas'а Rocha.
Вот ссылка на gitHub: https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view/

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора уточнить вопрос, оставьте комментарий к вопросу. Вы можете оставлять любое количество комментариев под своим сообщением. Когда ваша [репутация](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [комментировать сообщения любого пользователя](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/46110)

Answer (score 1):

`RecyclerView`, `CardView`, кастомная разметка элементов + гугл. Это максимально подробный ответ на ваш вопрос.

Comment: "кастомная разметка элементов" можете объяснить? Это как?

Comment: а как фото и видео такой плиткой выложить? Как такое гуглить?

Comment: @antop95, "кастомная" - значит своя, руками написанная под свои нужды. Скорее всего готовых способов так расположить нет. Но можно попробовать погуглить "android image gallery view/widject"